# Assigning method to prototype not working

Tags: javascript, function, constructor, closures, prototype

```
function Test(){
  this.name = "Hello World";
  function sayName(){
    return this.name;
  }
}
Test.prototype.callName = function(){
    return `Hello my name is, ${this.name}`;
}
const me = new Test();
me.callName();
console.log(me);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Test { name: 'Hello World' }
```

1. why is the function sayName is not in the instance of the object.
2. why is the me.callName() function call is not working

Comment: `console.log(me.callName())` ...

Comment: thank you @JonasWilms. and can you answer the logic behind the first question? Like why can't i call sayName() on 'me'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why is the function sayName is not in the instance of the object.

because you didn't assign it.

```
this.sayName = sayName;
```

> why is the me.callName() function call is not working

IDK it works for me

```js
function Test(){
  this.name = "Hello World";
  this.sayName = function sayName(){
    return this.name;
  }
}
Test.prototype.callName = function(){
    return `Hello my name is, ${this.name}`;
}
const me = new Test();
console.log(me.sayName());
console.log(me.callName());
```

Comment: thanks. but still confused why i need to assign it to this.sayName ?

Comment: This is an old API and that is how it works. You should really be using class declarations https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are making an oject of the `Test()` using the `new` keyword. The following things happen when you create an
object instance using the `new` keyword

1. an new empty oject is created
2. prototype link of the empty object is linked with `Test`
3. the value of `this` is bound to `Test.prototype`
4. It executes the constructor function, using the newly created object whenever this is mentioned
5. the newly created object is returned
6. if `Test()` has a return value then that value is returned instead.

So in the process you are infact permanently binding the value of `this` to `Test` so `this.name` can become `Test.name`.

The `this` binding doesn't happen if you simply call `me = Test` ,without `new`. In that case, `this` will actually refer to the global scope.

You can acess `sayName` if you had written `this.sayName = function sayName(){...}`

`me.callName` works via **behaviour delegation** . it is the feature of js where you're indicating an object to delegate behavior to if that behavior isn't defined on the object in question. `Test.callName` does not exist , so it traverses up the prototype link and finds a `callName` function in the `prototype` object which is used.

Finally , I would really suggest you learn the inner workings of `new` , `Object.create` & `prototype degation`. Although the `class` keyword currently exist in javascript , It is merely a syntactic sugar around how the `new` keyword works and not the same to same implementation of how `class` works in `object oriented languages` such as `java` . IMO, I would suggest you learn more about `new , Object.create` also as they are also very much used in modern code :)

[this post is worth noting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript)